# iPhone - keyboard with OK button to dismiss, with return key accepted in the UITextView

Tags: iphone, button, keyboard, uitextview, dismiss

I'm searching for a good method to display a keyboard with a done button to allow it to dismiss when the user have finished modifying a UITextView. The UITextView may accept return keys so I can't use the keyboard button to dismiss it.

It would be also really great if this keyboard was modal, or if a click anywhere on another control than the UITextView would dismiss it.

Do you know how to do it and do it well ?

I tried a lot of code found on the Web, and I'm a little bit tired for now trying to make such a simple and standard thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html).

Also, you don't "click" in iOS, you "tap".

Comment: Thank you. While I'm trying, can you tell me if you know how to prevent theuser to make changes in the windows while editing the textView (modal keyboard... transparent things... resign everywhere...) ?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it's better usability-wise to set up the controls in a standard way and let the user get on with it rather than micromanaging the user's interactions.  Most of the time when people ask me to do something like this, it's because they are trying to ignore the medium and break platform conventions.  Apple seem to deliberately design the SDK to make this difficult.

Comment: I've read the apple doc, but I can't achieve setting the inputAccessoryView. Can you help me to place the code at the right place ? I'm initing with a nib.

Comment: Every UIResponder subclass (such as UITextView) has the inputAccessoryView property.  So you need to assign a view to that property for each text view you want to have the extra button.  Create an IBOutlet in your view controller for the text view, then hook it up in Interface Builder.  Then when your view is being set up, set the inputAccessoryView on the IBOutlet.

Comment: Ouch... I've implemented the Apple example. Ouch... What a crazy amount of code for such a simple things. It's just incredible ! keyboardWillHide, keyboardWillShow, textViewShouldEndEditing, textViewShouldBeginEditing, textEditingDone, addObserver..... I'm going crazy !